# what is the difference between list<> and dictionary<> in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, dictionary

I  have a strange doubt regarding list and dictionary in c#

In a list we add items to list by using the following method

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       List<int> list = new List<int>();
       list.Add(2);
       list.Add(3);
       list.Add(5);
       list.Add(7);
    }
}
```

In a dictionary we add items like this ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
      d.Add("cat", 2);
      d.Add("dog", 1);
      d.Add("llama", 0);
      d.Add("iguana", -1);
   }
}
```

I don't know exactly what is the difference, but in a dictionary we add items like a (key,value) pair and in a list we just add items without specifying any key ..

Would anyone clarify this?

Comment: Your question is quite self-explanatory ;-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`IDictionary` is for key->value maps, `ICollection` is for sets of similar objects.

`ICollection` is an interface for collections of similar objects: the controls on a form, the elements in a list, the attributes in an XML tag, and so on. As of .NET 2.0, there's a generic version, so you can refer to a collection of integers as `ICollection<int>`.

IDictionary is an interface for mapping one type of object or value to another. It works like a real dictionary, or a phone book: you have a "key" in mind like a person’s name, and when you look it up, you get some information that’s identified by that key, like an address or phone number. Each key can only be listed once, although two different keys are still allowed to have the same value. This is also generic in .NET 2.0, so a dictionary whose keys are strings and whose values are integers would be `IDictionary<string,int>`.

A dictionary is actually a collection of key/value pairs: you can use an `IDictionary<int,string>` as an `ICollection<KeyValuePair<int,string>>`, and you can access the keys and values as separate collections with the Keys and Values properties.

Both `ICollection` and `IDictionary` are unordered, meaning that although you can retrieve the elements in some order with the `CopyTo` method or a foreach loop, that order has no special meaning, and it might change for no apparent reason. That’s the main difference between `ICollection` and `IList`: a list lets you put items in specific positions, just like an array, and they stay there until you move them.

Comment: check the below 2 links for examples:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Answer (score 14):

`List<>` and `Dictionary<,>` - pretty different data structures which used for different purposes, List is simply a set of items and Dictionary is a set of key-value pairs.

Dictionary is pretty useful when you have a set of complex objects and want to have fast access by let's say ObjectName/ObjectId, in this case you create `IDictionary<string, TObject>` where key would be ObjectId and Value would be an object itself.

Some differences:

- List persist order of the items, Dictionary does not
- List allow fast access by index
- List support built in QuickSort algorithm for fast data sorting
- Dictionary allows ~`O(1)` time complexity to access an item (value) by a key

Answer (score 13):

- `Dictionary<K,V>` is an associative array, or map. It is a container that can be indexed by values of any type.
- `List<T>` is an integer indexed array. It is a container that is indexed by contiguous integers.

The essential difference therefore is in how the containers are indexed.

Don't fall into the trap of believing that `Dictionary<int,T>` is semantically equivalent to `List<T>`. The difference is that the indexing of `List<T>` is contiguous whereas there can be *gaps* in the indexing for `Dictionary<int,T>`.

Answer (score 3):

List: In the list, it is possible to add duplicate record.

Dictionary: In dictionary key must be unique. It is not possible to add duplicate key in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class library which accesses a variety of T-sql sprocs; each sproc returns a single row but varying columns. I needed a general purpose solution for an retrieving the values and Dictionary<> provided a much cleaner solution than List<>.

The class common to all of the wrappers declares

```
public Dictionary<string, String> datadict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

and

```
public Dictionary<string, String> LoadData(string sproc, string paramName, string paramValue)
```

Invoking a Reader, the datadict is loaded with

```
for (int i = Reader.FieldCount; i != 0; i--)
 {
  datadict.Add(Reader.GetName(i - 1).Trim(), Reader.GetString(i - 1).Trim());
 }
```

and returns datadict to the calling class which can then retrieve the data much like Reader does; E.g.:

```
datadict = myData.LoadData("spGetSSN", "", "");
  ssn1 = datadict["SSN1"];
  ssn2 = datadict["SSN2"];
  ssn3 = datadict["SSN3"];
```

Much cleaner for me that List<>.

Answer (score 0):

Elements in a list have the following characteristics:

They maintain their ordering unless explicitly re-ordered (for example, by sorting the list).
They can be of any type, and types can be mixed.
They are accessed via numeric (zero based) indices.
Elements in a Dictionary have the following characteristics:

Every entry has a key and a value
Ordering is not guaranteed
Elements are accessed using key values
Key values can be of any hashtable type (i.e. not a dict) and types can be mixed
Values can be of any type (including other dict’s), and types can be mixed