# How to replace an element in KeyValuePair<> List<>

Tags: c#

Okay, I have this KeyValuePair list:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>> values { get; set; }
```

Now I want to know if there is already this element. I tried this with:

```
bool conaintsValue = values.Contains(value);
```

But how do I replace this element now?
This is what I tried:

```
if(values.Contains(value))
{
    int i = values.IndexOf(value);
    values[i] = value;
}
```

But this does not work.

EDIT:
I add a value like this! Values = List!

```
KeyValuePair<string, float> value = new KeyValuePair<string, float>(chartKey, chartValue);
```

This is my list:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>> values { get; set; }
```

Comment: You replace the value with the same value.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace `value` with itself? Have you checked whether `values.Contains(value)` is returning `true` or not?

Comment: Because my program can Change the value `float`and the key `string` stays the same. And I want to Change this element at the same index.

Comment: Also, don't call `Contains` followed by `IndexOf` as they both have to scan the list. Just call `IndexOf` and if the return index is `-1` you know the item isn't in the list.

Comment: Would this not be easier with a Dictionary of some type?

Comment: @ClickRick I never used a Dictionary I just heared of it. If its not so much can you give me a Little Code and Explanation ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7914854/6071824

Comment: @ChristopherLake thank you!

Comment: You can use Dictionary<string, float> instead of ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>> but you will loose the specific features of ObservableCollection. Maybe you use it in a WPF binding.

Comment: I'm using this in a WPF Toolkit chart. So I Need a list that updates itself. Don't know if this still working with Dictonary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this:

```
if (values.Contains(value))
{
    int i = values.IndexOf(value);
    KeyValuePair<string, float> newValue = new KeyValuePair<string, float>("test", (float)11.3);
    values[i] = newValue;
}
```

and it works. You should replace the old value with a new one not with the same value.

Comment: That answered this question. Now I have a different Problem but its not about this :) Thank you!