# What is the difference between Tuple, Dictionary and List in C#?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, tuples

The differences between Lists and Dictionaries are already shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914830/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-dictionary-in-c-sharp).

However, I was trying to use Tuple in an application earlier. I want to differentiate between Tuples, Dictionaries, and Lists.

```
 Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 Tuple<int, string> tuple = new Tuple<int, string>();
 List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

What is the difference between these three?

Comment: Is there really something like `List<int, string>`?

Comment: Does your list even compile?

Comment: "This question already has answer here" And why ask it again?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Please see the link which has not differentiate tuple.

Comment: So you should mention that within your question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, AFAIK, there isn't any list that takes two type parameters - so your List could either be a `List<int>` or `List<string>` (or a `SortedList<int,string>`, but that's a different class).

A [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) holds two values - one int and one string in this case. You can use a Tuple to bind together items (that might be of different
types). This may be useful in many situations, like, for instance, you want to return more than one value from a method.

I personally hate the `Item1`, `Item2` property names, so I would probably use a wrapper class around Tuples in my code.

A [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) is a collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. A Dictionary maps keys to values, so that you can have, for instance, a dictionary of people and for each person have their [SSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number) as a key.

A [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) is a collection of `T`.
You can get individual items by using the index, the `Find` method, or simply [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) (since it implements `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: I think in C# 8 tuples got much better in the sense that you don't need to see Item1 and Item2 anymore. You just give a name. And instead of having to create Tuple<T1, T2>, you can just define your type as (T1 Name1, T2 Name2). 
Instead of Tuple<int, string> tuple = new Tuple<int, string>();
You do: 
(int id, string value) tuple = (myId, myValue);

Comment: @digaomatias There are also other differences between [`System.Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=net-6.0) and [`Syste.ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 2):

A list can store a sequence of objects in a certain order such that you can index into the list, or iterate over the list. List is a mutable type meaning that lists can be modified after they have been created.

A tuple is similar to a list except it is immutable. There is also a semantic difference between a list and a tuple. To quote Nikow's answer:

> Tuples have structure, lists have order.

A dictionary is a key-value store. It is not ordered and it requires that the keys are hashable. It is fast for lookups by key.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer you have linked discusses the differentiation between `List<T>` and `Dictionary<int, T>`, `Tuple<int, string>` is not addressed.

From MSDN

> Represents a 2-tuple, or pair.

A tuple is a pair of values, opposed to the other types, which represent sort of collections. Think of a method, which returns an error code and string for the last error (I would not write the code this way, but to get the idea)

```
Tuple<int, string> GetLastError()
{
    ...
}
```

Now you can use it like

```
var lastError = GetLastError();
Console.WriteLine($"Errorcode: {lastError.Item1}, Message: {lastError.Item2}");
```

This way you do not have to create a class, if you want to return a compound value.

**Please Note**: As of C# 7 there is a newer, more concise syntax for returning tuples.

Answer (score 1):

So for the difference between a `Dictionary` and a `List` you've seen the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7914830/6400526). So what is a `Tuple`? By MSDN:

> A tuple is a data structure that has a specific number and sequence of values. The `Tuple<T1, T2>` class represents a 2-tuple, or pair, which is a tuple that has two components. A 2-tuple is similar to a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure.

While the two other data structures represent different **collections** of items (generic to be whatever type you declare) a `Tuple<T1,....>` is a **single item** containing a predefined amount of properties - similar to defining a class with  few properties.

As the two first ones are collections of items and a tuple is a single item they play very different roles in terms of what to do with them.

Read more on

- MSDN - [common uses for tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

In addition you can have a look at [What requirement was the tuple designed to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3089706/6400526)